# Have child object inherit from a specific parent object

Tags: c#, inheritance

I'm working on teaching myself C# and have a question about inheritance from a specific instance of a parent object.
For example if I define my classes as such:

```
class League
{
    public string name { get; set; }
}
class Player : League
{
    public Guid PlayerGuid { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
class Team : Player
{
    public Guid TeamGuid { get; set; }
    public string TeamName { get; set; }
}
```

Then instantiate the classes as such:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        League myLeague = new League() { name = "The League" };
        Player taco = new Player() { PlayerGuid = Guid.NewGuid(), FirstName = "Taco", LastName = "MacArthur" };
        Player pete = new Player() { PlayerGuid = Guid.NewGuid(), FirstName = "Pete", LastName = "Eckhart" };
        Team tacoTeam = new Team() { TeamGuid = Guid.NewGuid(), TeamName = "Password is Taco" };
        Team peteTeam = new Team() { TeamGuid = Guid.NewGuid(), TeamName = "3-Pete" };
    }
```

How do I make sure that Team tacoTeam inherits from Player taco and Team peteTeam inherits from Player pete?

My feeling is that I'm not understanding how to define the classes properly for this case and would appreciate a pointer on how this should be done.

To clarify the relationship of the elements I've changed "Player" to "Owner" better represents what I have in mind.  I could further add a class for "Players" to represent the real players instead of the armchair players.

With input from @neoistheone and @McGarnagle I was able to revise this and defined the classes as such:

```
class League
{
    public string name { get; set; }
}
class Owner
{
    public Guid OwnerGuid { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
class Team
{
    public Guid TeamGuid { get; set; }
    public string TeamName { get; set; }
    public Owner TeamOwner { get; set; }
    public League League { get; set; }

}
```

I can then create an instance of the classes and get what out of them as such:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        League MyLeague = new League() { name = "The League" };
        Owner taco = new Owner() { FirstName = "Taco", LastName = "MacArthur", OwnerGuid = Guid.NewGuid() };
        Owner pete = new Owner() { FirstName = "Pete", LastName = "Eckhart", OwnerGuid = Guid.NewGuid() };
        Team tacoTeam = new Team() { TeamGuid = Guid.NewGuid(), TeamName = "Password is Taco", League = MyLeague, TeamOwner = taco };
        Team peteTeam = new Team() { TeamGuid = Guid.NewGuid(), TeamName = "3-Pete", League = MyLeague, TeamOwner = pete };

        List<Team> Teams = new List<Team>();
            Teams.Add(tacoTeam);
            Teams.Add(peteTeam);

        foreach(Team team in Teams){
            Console.WriteLine("Team Name:\t{0}\nTeam Owner:\t{1}\nLeague Name:\t{2}\n-----", 
                team.TeamName, team.TeamOwner.FirstName + " " + team.TeamOwner.LastName, team.League.name);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

This seems to do a pretty decent job of helping to model the data in my code to make it easier to get it into and out of a database I'm working on to go with this application.

Comment: Inheritance does not concern itself with specific instances of objects. The sample you provided does not make sense, these classes should not be inheriting from one another. Also, The League is gut-splittingly funny.

Comment: I think you completely misunderstood what inheritance is about...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Class inheritance implies an "is-a" relationship.  You don't want Player inheriting League for example, because that would imply that a player is a league.

Instead, what you want is *composition* -- leagues are composed of teams, which are composed of players.  You express composition by creating class members.  Class `Team` should have a member that is a collection of class `Player`, and so on.  For example:

```
class Player
{
    public Guid PlayerGuid { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

class Team
{
    public Guid TeamGuid { get; set; }
    public string TeamName { get; set; }
    public IList<Player> Players { get; private set; }

    public Team()
    {
        Players = new List<Player>();
    }
}

class League
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public IList<Team> Teams { get; private set; }

    public League()
    {
        Teams = new List<Team>();
    }
}
```

Now, to make sure Taco belongs to Team Taco, you add him to the corresponding instance of the `Team` class:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Player taco = new Player { PlayerGuid = Guid.NewGuid(), FirstName = "Taco", LastName = "MacArthur" };
    Player pete = new Player { PlayerGuid = Guid.NewGuid(), FirstName = "Pete", LastName = "Eckhart" };
    Team tacoTeam = new Team { TeamGuid = Guid.NewGuid(), TeamName = "Password is Taco" };
    Team peteTeam = new Team { TeamGuid = Guid.NewGuid(), TeamName = "3-Pete" };

    tacoTeam.Players.Add(taco);
    peteTeam.Players.Add(pete);

    League myLeague = new League { name = "The League" };
    myLeague.Teams.Add(tacoTeam);
    myLeague.Teams.Add(peteTeam);
}
```

Comment: +1... Also I'd say team "contains" players instead of "composed of"... But [composed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition) is probably the better word (assuming team "owns" players, and there is no other collection that owns them like "AllPlayersInTheCountry")

Comment: Thank you all for the input on this.  I wasn't understanding how inheritance worked. I think I understand how to accomplish what I'm after now.

Answer (score 1):

This statement is strange to say the least:

> How do I make sure that Team tacoTeam inherits from Player taco and Team peteTeam inherits from Player pete?

The fact of the matter is, inheritance doesn't necessarily have anything to do with the objects you've created. Team inherits from Player... that's it.

I'm a little confused where the question is coming from, though I would like to point out that this inheritance is odd:

```
class Team : Player
```

I don't see how a *team* would inherit from a *player*. Are you sure you should be inheriting at all?

Think of it this way. As the others have pointed out, inheritance implies an "is-a" relationship. It doesnt make any sense to say that a Team is a Player, neither does it make sense to say that a Player is a Team. A Team is *composed of* players. That does not suggest there should be any inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

Take a step back and just think about how it works in real life. A `League` has one or more `Team`s and a `Team` has one or more `Player`s. That's how you want to structure your classes:

```
class League
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public List<Team> Teams { get; set; }
}

class Team
{
    public Guid TeamGuid { get; set; }
    public string TeamName { get; set; }
    public List<Player> Players { get; set; }
}

class Player
{
    public Guid PlayerGuid { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

and so now you might do something like this:

```
var league = new League()
{
    name = "AFC",
    Teams = new List<Team>()
};

var team = new Team()
{
    TeamGuid = Guid.NewGuid(),
    TeamName = "Chicago Bears",
    Players = new List<Player>()
}
league.Teams.Add(team);

var player = new Player()
{
    PlayerGuid = Guid.NewGuid(),
    FirstName = "Test",
    LastName = "Player"
};
team.Players.Add(player);
```

But as far as this is concerned:

> How do I make sure that Team tacoTeam inherits from Player taco and Team peteTeam inherits from Player pete?

That's not what inheritance is for. Inheritance is so that you could extend `Player` for example into a `Linebacker`:

```
public class Linebacker : Player
{
    public int Tackles { get; set; }
}
```

See, not **every** `Player` has `Tackles` as a statistic, but a `Linebacker` would. You could abstract that even more, but I just wanted to give an example.

Answer (score 0):

You're misusing inheritance in this example. Consider the simple example of a shape.

```
class Shape
{
    Color Color { get; set; }
}

class Rectangle : Shape
{
    double SideA { get; set; }
    double SideB { get; set; }
}

class Square : Rectangle
{
}
```

You can see that a Square is a Rectangle, and a Rectangle is a Square. All three have a color. Rectangles have two sets of equal sides. Square has some other more specific attributes.

Your structure should follow something more along these lines:

```
class League
{
    public Team[] Teams { get; set; }
}

class Team
{
    public League League { get; set; }
    public Player[] Players { get; set; }
}

class Player
{
    public Team Team { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you full understand inheritance.  In this instance, there isn't really any.

A League would consist of a collection of teams, and a team would consist of a collection of players.

```
class League
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public List<Team> Teams { get; set; }
}

class Team
{
    public Guid TeamGuid { get; set; }
    public string TeamName { get; set; }
    public List<Player> Players { get; set; }
}

class Player
{
    public Guid PlayerGuid { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Inheritance in this instance would be if you had different types of leagues, e.g. a BaseballLeague and a FootballLeague, so in that instance they would inherit from League in addition to having other properties,

```
class BaseballLeague : League
{
    public string SomeOtherProperty { get; set; }
}
```